# AngularJS ng-repeat hide items -> compare to other JSON object

Tags: angularjs, json, object, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-hide

I'm doing ng-repeat over an object structured like this:

```
Object{
  id: 'id',
  name: 'name'
  colours:[
   {
      colour_id: 'id',
      colour_name: 'name'
   },
      {
      colour_id: 'id',
      colour_name: 'name'
   }
  ]
};
```

I have another object defined inside my controlled which is like:

```
Colours = {
   'id1':'name1',
   'id2':'name2',
   'id3':'nam3',
   ..
 };
```

What I wanna do in ng-repeat is that I want to compare every colours colours_id and colour_name with Colours object and check if both of values match to not show them if they already exist.

Something like

```
<li ng-repeat='colour in Object.colours' 
    ng-hide='colour.colour_id == Colours_id && colour.colour_id == Colours_name'>
</li>
```

The problem is, how can I 'loop' through my Colours object from controller, if it does not have id/name but the values instead? How can I compare those values?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat='colour in Object.colours'
    ng-hide='Colours[colour.colour_id] && Colours[colour.colour_id] == colour.colour_name'>
</li>
```

Comment: It's not going to work, comparing id to name it's just obviously bad, they are not related. The problem here is to compare my ng-repeat values with Colours object values like show color if color.name == Colours.name && color.id == Colours.id. These values HAVE TO BE in pairs, as id is strictly bound to the name.

Comment: I'm not comparing id with name actually, Colours[colour.colour_id] - it is a name, not id. (E.g. Colours['id1'] = 'name1')